# Arduino project on a server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, server, arduino

I am building a project with asp.net that connects to Arduino Uno. I am connecting some magnetic sensors to the Arduino and I want the results of the sensors to be updated in real time within my database in the project at asp.net.

So far everything worked fine.

My college gave me a server where I was supposed to set up my site and put up the project.

When I work on my computer (regardless of the server) I see that the Arduino is connected to COM3. But when I connect to the server the Arduino does not appear connected (I guess because the Arduino is connected to my computer and not to the server computer).

I know there is a possibility to buy an Ethernet shield / wifi shield but I want to avoid it.

Is there another possibility to transfer the data received from the Arduino in my computer, to the database on the server?

The server is a Windows server with IIS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a sharing folder with premissions from the sever and then put the entire asp.net project and now he recognize tha Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino needs to be able to connect to the server. You could connect it directly to the server or have a client on your computer talking to both the Arduino and the server.

Or you could use a Raspberry pi or other device capable of communicating directly to your database server over the network.

Comment: can you explain me more about it  - "or have a client on your computer talking to both the Arduino and the server"

Comment: Yes, you could write an application that runs on your computer and communicates with the arduino to get the data. That's one part of it. The other part is to connect to the database and store the data the application recieved. Not my favorite approach, but it should work.